# Group table by category

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, html-table

This is my second question I have:

I do have this mysql table:

Category:

- id-name-catnom
- 1 -test-1
- 2 -te4t-1
- 3 -te5t-2
- 4 -t85t-3
- 5 -t75t-4
- and so on

Now I want to Group by category and order by name to have an output like this:

[image: Wanted output]

I tried it with:

```
<div class="grid js-masonry"  data-masonry-options='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 205 }'>           
<?php
$category= ORM::for_table('category')->group_by('catnom')->find_many();
foreach ($category as $cat):
$prods = ORM::for_table('products')->order_by_asc('name')->where('idcat', $cat->id)->find_many();
?>

<div class="grid-item" style="width: 180px">
    <table class="table table-hover table-nomargin table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>    
                <td><?php echo $cat->name?></td>
            </tr>     
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>    
</div>
```

[IdiORM]

but it only shows one category instead off all categories. Any suggestion how to get this working?

Comment: your question is not clear  try add  text and not image    ..

Comment: Have you printed the results of $category to verify that you are combining categories correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($category as $cat):
$prods = ORM::for_table('products')->order_by_asc('name')->where('idcat', $cat->id)->find_many();
```

In this code, you're overwriting the variable `$prods` in each iteration of the loop, so in the end you'll only get the products for the last category looped.

You could do something like this:

```
foreach ($category as $cat):
$prods[$cat->id] = ORM::for_table('products')->order_by_asc('name')->where('idcat', $cat->id)->find_many();
```

Now each set of products is stored in the array $prods, and anytime you want to get the products for a specific category you'll use `$prods[{id}]`, where `{id}` is the category ID you want to get the products for.

Comment: i updated the question, as the problem starts at the categories.
with
'group_by('catnom')' it only shows 1 category each "column" without this , it shows all

Comment: Why are you grouping by `catnom`?

Comment: Catnom presents a number, so I want all categories which belongs to 1 among themselves, then 2nd row with number 2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by catnom will only, as you already saw, give you one category for each catnom, and it's supposed to work like that. The "grouping" you're referring to is a different thing. What you actually need to do is to to order by catnom and then by name. In other words:

```
$category= ORM::for_table('category')->find_many();
foreach ($category as $cat):
    ORM::for_table('products')->order_by_asc('catnom')->order_by_asc('name')->where('idcat', $cat->id)->find_many();
```

I tried posting this as a comment, but struggled too much with the code format. I'm still new to this.